# Is it possible to bulk replace strings in an Excel file via API?

Tags: excel, api, google-sheets, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to bulk replace strings in an Excel file via API?

Hello, I am aware that Google Sheets has an API called "FindReplaceRequest" (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)
which can be used to replace values in a spreadsheet with any desired string.

I am interested in achieving the same functionality in Microsoft Excel. I have come across the Microsoft Graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)
but I am not sure if this API can be used or if there are other methods available to achieve this.

Could you please advise if it is possible to replace strings in an Excel file via Microsoft Graph API?
If not, how can I do that with any other methods?

I would greatly appreciate any insights as I am not very familiar with Microsoft services, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph to invoke any workbook [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-use-functions).

Check list of supported [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.functions?view=excel-js-preview&preserve-view=true).

Example for [replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.functions?view=excel-js-preview&preserve-view=true#excel-excel-functions-replace-member(1))

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/root:/path/to/file/fileName.xlsx:/workbook/functions/replace
content-type: Application/Json 
authorization: Bearer {access-token} 
workbook-session-id: {session-id}

{
    "oldText": "old text",
    "startNum": 0,
    "numChars": 8,
    "newText": "new text"
}
```

Comment: hello again, thank you for the answer! is this api possible to update excel worksheet with replaced text(new text)? I tried this api and could obtain replaced text itself, but could not update excel file.